# slf4j error with Htmlunit Maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, htmlunit

With the following Maven dependency for Htmlunit,

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the following error,

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/mnkb/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/mnkb/.m2/repository/org/apache/activemq/activemq-all/5.12.0/activemq-all-5.12.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

In my pom.xml, I have even commented out the following dependency,

```xml
<!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mattbertolini</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->
```

Comment: you can refere my pom.xml  at the SO post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581831/unable-to-run-htmlunit-application-using-maven-dependency/33603254#33603254. I am using that same pom.xml, but now I am getting slf4j error.

Answer (score 0):

The `activemq-all` dependency seems to be an uberjar that contains slf4j. Some other dependency seems to pull in slf4j as well. That's why you get this error. If you can try to get rid of the `activemq-all` dependency, maybe by using `activemq-core`. Seems to be an issue with ActiveMQ's packaging (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5009).